# Formulário não direciona para outra página ao usar MPDF

Tags: php, mpdf

Tenho um formulário que quando enviado, executa uma action que direciona para outra página PHP, onde são executados vários scripts e no final é gerado um arquivo PDF para download.

Todos os scripts e a geração do PDF são executados corretamente, porém, em vez de direcionar para a página referenciada em action, que além de executar os scripts, também tem a função de mostrar uma mensagem de sucesso ou de erro, o sistema continua na tela do formulário, passando a impressão para o usuário de que o formulário não foi enviado, possivelmente ocasionando em registros duplicados.

Início e final do form:

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="function.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" value="Enviar">
```

Código PHP para geração do PDF:

```
header('Pragma: no-cache');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
$mpdf=new mPDF(); 
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
$html = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
$stylesheet = file_get_contents('_css/pdf_style.css');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html,2);
$mpdf->Output('myPDF.pdf', 'D');
$mpdf->charset_in='windows-1252';
```

Demonstração do que acontece após o envio do formulário:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já verifiquei a documentação do MPDF mas não encontrei função que resolvesse esse problema. Seria esse um comportamento normal do MPDF ou está faltando alguma configuração do MPDF ou PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos ver, mesmo o seu formulário HTML tendo 2 botões de `submit` deve funcionar.

O seu PHP está correto, o que entendi é que o PHP alterá o cabeçalho do **function.php** para o MIME-TYPE pela própria API, algo assim:

*header("Content-type:application/pdf")*

Então por sua vez o navegador por padrão baixa o PDF e a página não segue por que algo impede de abrir diretamente o PDF ou o seu navegador está programado para baixar automaticamente.

Pra resolver isso você pode apenas para passar as informações para o **funciton.php** e essa página redirecionar com variaveis GET para outra que gere baixe o PDF, por exemplo **dlpdf.php** em método get ou mesmo método POST com AJAX.

De qualquer maneira faça o teste com esse exemplo, pra ver se abre diretamente.

```
<?php 
 include("mpdf60/mpdf.php");
 $html = "
 <fieldset>
 <h1>Recibo de Pagamento</h1>
 <p class='center sub-titulo'>
 Nº <strong>0001</strong> - 
 VALOR <strong>R$ 700,00</strong>
 </p>
 <p>Recebi(emos) de <strong>Ebrahim Paula Leite</strong></p>
 <p>a quantia de <strong>Setecentos Reais</strong></p>
 <p>Correspondente a <strong>Serviços prestados ..<strong></p>
 <p>e para clareza firmo(amos) o presente.</p>
 <p class='direita'>Itapeva, 11 de Julho de 2017</p>
 <p>Assinatura ......................................................................................................................................</p>
 <p>Nome <strong>Alberto Nascimento Junior</strong> CPF/CNPJ: <strong>222.222.222-02</strong></p>
 <p>Endereço <strong>Rua Doutor Pinheiro, 144 - Centro, Itapeva - São Paulo</strong></p>
 </fieldset>
 <div class='creditos'>
 <p><a href='https://www.webcreative.com.br/artigo/gerar-pdf-com-php-e-html-usando-a-biblioteca-mpdf' target='_blank'>Aprenda como gerar PDF com PHP e HTML usando a biblioteca MPDF aqui</a></p>
 </div>
 ";

 $mpdf=new mPDF(); 
 $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
 $css = file_get_contents("css/estilo.css");
 $mpdf->WriteHTML($css,1);
 $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
 $mpdf->Output();
 exit;
?>
```

E se não der certo tente usar esse sistema:
**[DOMPDF](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf)**